# Como posso fazer um select por data e por hora

Tags: php, mysql

Bom o que pretendo inicialmente é fazer um while que me mostre todos os resultados da minha coluna reservas. Contudo eu quero fazer um select que me mostre os dias mais próximos e de seguida as horas mais próximas.

O nome da minha coluna de dias é "dialevant" e o nome da minha hora de levantamento é "horalevant", como poderei fazer para que faça um select que me mostre os dias mais próximos e de seguida as horas?

Obrigado.

Comment: Se dialevant sempre vai armazenar datas anteriores ou iguais a data atual você pode efetuar um SELECT na sua tabela utilizando "ORDER BY dialevant DESC, horalevant DESC" ao final da sua consulta.

Comment: Não, o dialevant, só vai armazenar datas futuras ou datas atuais cuja a hora ainda não passou da horalevant.

Comment: Pode posta a estrutura da suas tabelas e como esta trazendo os dados e como você quer?

Answer (score 0):

Se o dia e a hora estão separados, então os junte com DATETIMEFROMPARTS. Seu formato é:

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds )
```

Então, tente algo como:

```
SELECT *
FROM reservas
WHERE DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                       YEAR(dialevant),
                       MONTH(dialevant),
                       DAY(dialevant),
                       HOUR(horalevant),
                       MINUTE(horalevant),
                       0,
                       0) > DATETIME("SUA DATA AQUI")
ORDER BY DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                       YEAR(dialevant),
                       MONTH(dialevant),
                       DAY(dialevant),
                       HOUR(horalevant),
                       MINUTE(horalevant),
                       0,
                       0) ASC
```

Espero que ajude.